# Tkinter individual key events

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry if duplicated. I need a tkinter event to execute something ONLY if the user pressed certain keys, specifically, the keys from the 0 to the 9, whatever it is on the numpad or the normal keyboard. Are there any? I remember so, but I can't find anything.

Comment: See [Bindings and Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events).

Comment: See also https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html for a list of the key names.